# How do i fix this null pointer error on line 75?

Tags: android, pointers, null

[Null Pointer error on line 75 of start activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UruyZ.jpg)

Comment: I suppose `findViewById` doesn't find anything. But don't paste code as text. And give some context, the error is just at the top of the visible snippet.

Comment: Thank you PMF for the link. I will take a look at it and try to solve the error. How do i enter a code into the question? I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: Take the tour (from the question mark menu in the top right corner). You can also find information about formatting code and text in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception in your case is thrown because the compiler can't find any view with the given id i.e. there is no view with id "home". Just create a "home" id for your desired view and this error will no more bother you.